# Cambiar color de texto de navbar bootstrap4

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3

Tengo un navbar de bootstrap 4 pero quiero cambiarle el color al texto pero no no me deja, estoy intentando llamar desde el CSS la clase que contiene al texto 
y nada que me deja cambiarle el color, solo me deja si se lo cambio directamente desde el HTML

```css
.container-fluid header nav ul li a {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-md-between flex-row" id="navbar-container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="" height="50px;">
  </div>

  <header id="header" class="d-flex justify-content-md-center">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  ">
          <li class="nav-item active centrado">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quienes Somos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado pl-3" id="socialnav">
            <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado" id="socialnav">
            <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado" id="socialnav">
            <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header><!-- /header -->
```

Comment: Nada, acabo de agregarle eso (agregandole la c al container) y nada sigue sin funcionar haciendo un llamado desde el CSS

Comment: Solo debes agregar la propiedad !important para que sobreescriba los estilos de bootstrap por los tuyos

Answer (score 1):

Agrega **!important**

```
 .container-fluid header nav ul li a{
    color: orange !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te explico brevemente, ***Boostrap*** ya trae sus colores predefinidos en sus clases, para lograr cambiarlos mi recomendación es modificar esos atributos específicamente. 
El selector que utiliza es **.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link** 

Y por supuesto hay que poner esos estilos **después** de donde se hace la referencia a el CSS de ***Boostrap*** para que respete nuestras modificaciones.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
/* Este es para los elementos en general */
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
color: orange;
}
/*  Este es para el elemento activo lo puedes omitir si asi deseas */
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link  {
 color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-md-between flex-row" id="navbar-container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="" height="50px;">
  </div>

  <header id="header" class="d-flex justify-content-md-center">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  ">
          <li class="nav-item active centrado">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quienes Somos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado pl-3" id="socialnav">
            <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado" id="socialnav">
            <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item centrado" id="socialnav">
            <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- /header -->
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que los colores se muestran porque son llamados después de los estilos de boostrap, si se llaman antes predominarían los de bootstrap. Esto porque si son iguales los selectores predomina la que se llama al último

Answer (score 0):

recuerda debes quitarle la decoration por defecto que trae la etiqueta a ejemplo

```
.ontainer-fluid header nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color: orange;

}
```